# Django JSONField with default and custom encoder

Tags: mysql, json, python-3.x, django

Django version: 3.1.0, MySQL backend

I have a `JSONField` on my model:

```py
class Employee(models.Model):
    address = models.JSONField(
        encoder=AddressEncoder,
        dedocer=AddressDecoder,
        default=address_default
    )
```

Then the `encoder` looks like this:

```py
class AddressEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, Address):
            return dataclasses.asdict(o)
        raise TypeError("An Address instance is required, got an {0}".format(type(o)))
```

Then the `address_default` looks like this:

```py
def address_default():
    encoder = AddressEncoder()
    address = Addres(...)
    return encoder.encode(address)
```

Currently I have set the `address_default` to return a `dict`. Although it should actually return an `Address` instance. When I change this so that the `address_default` returns an instance of `Address`, an error is raised `TypeError: Object of type Address is not JSON serializable`. However, in other parts of the code where the address is in fact an instance of `Address`, no errors are raised. So the custom `AddressEncoder` does not seem to be used on the value provided by the `address_default`.

When the address `attribute` on `Employee` is set to e.g. a `string`, no error is thrown. This might have to do with what is explained in [Why is Django not using my custom encoder class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53179125/why-is-django-not-using-my-custom-encoder-class). The code in `AddressEncoder` is not executed.

**Question:**

What is the correct way to set up the `address_default`, and `Encoder/Decoder` so that the `address` attribute can be, and only be, an instance of `Address`?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. It had to do with my migrations. One of my migrations contained a definition of the `address`-field without the encoders. Hence changing the `address_default` to return a non json serializable object throws the corresponding error.

I had to manually find and change that migrations so that the definition of the `address` field includes the custom encoder.

The check `isinstance(self.address, Address)` is then done in an overridden `save()` method on the `Employee` model.